# YII gridview filter not working

Tags: gridview, filter, yii

I totally lost in Yii gridview filter. There is a gridview on a view page, which is student/view.

Here is the controller from StudentController:

```
/**
 * Displays a particular model.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
 */
public function actionView($id) {
    $this->layout = "//layouts/column1";
    $this->render('view', array(
        'model' => $this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

But! I want to show and filter the hours of the given student in a gridview from the HOUR model(not student model). So here is the part of the view file:

```
<?php
$hour = new Hour();
$hour->student_id = $model->id;
$hour->time_start = $startDate;

$hour->time_end = $endDate;
?>
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BsGridView', array(
    'id' => 'hour-grid',
//  'dataProvider' => $hourModel->StudentHoursSearch($model->id),
    'dataProvider' => $hour->search(),
    'filter'=>$hour,
    'columns' => array(
        //'student_id',
        array(
            'name' => 'instructor_id',
            'value' => '$data->instructor->name',
            'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Instructor::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'time_start',
            'value' => 'date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data->time_start))."<br />".date("H:i", strtotime($data->time_start))',
            'type' => 'html',
        ),
        'hour_topic',
        array(
            'name' => 'type',
            'type' => 'html',
            'value' => '$data->ticket_lease == "lease" ? $data->getTypeLabel() : ($data->ticket_lease == "ticket" ? $data->getTypeLabel() . " (jegy)" : ($data->cancel_type == 3 ? $data->getTypeLabel() . "<br />DK lemondás" : (date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data->time_start)) == date("Y-m-d") ? $data->getTypeLabel() : $data->getTypeLabel() . " <br/>Nincs lezárva")))',
            'filter' => Hour::$type_labels
        ),
    /* array(
      'name' => 'hour_topic',
      'value'=>'$data->hour_topic'
      ), */
    ),
    'rowCssClassExpression' => '                    
        $data->cancel_type == 3 ? "drumkiller_cancel" : ($data->type === "presenter" ? "student_presenter" : ($data->type === "training" ? "student_training" : "student_practice"))                    
    ',
));
?>
```

This shows all hours of the student very well, but the filtering functions are not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5L4H.png)

I want to use the two dropdown filter but none of them are working.

Here is the model of Hour:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search() {
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->with = array(
        'instructor',
        'student',
        // 'drumKit',
        'leaseOrder',
    );

    $criteria->compare('t.id', $this->id);
    $criteria->compare('t.instructor_id', $this->instructor_id);
    $criteria->compare('t.student_id', $this->student_id, true);
    // $criteria->compare('t.drum_kit_id', $this->drum_kit_id);
    $criteria->compare('t.lease_order_id', $this->lease_order_id);
    $criteria->compare('t.price', $this->price);
    $criteria->compare('t.type', $this->type, true);
    $criteria->compare('t.create_time', $this->create_time, true);
    $criteria->compare('t.hour_topic', $this->hour_topic, true);
    if (isset($_GET['time_start']) || isset($_GET['time_end'])) {
        $criteria->compare('t.time_start', '>=' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['time_strat'])));
        $criteria->compare('t.time_end', '<=' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['time_end'])));
    } else {

        if ($this->time_start && $this->time_end) {
            $criteria->compare('t.time_start', '>=' . $this->time_start);
            $criteria->compare('t.time_end', '<=' . $this->time_end);
        } else {
            $criteria->compare('t.time_start', $this->time_start, true);
            $criteria->compare('t.time_end', $this->time_end, true);
        }
    }
//  $criteria->compare('cancel_type', array(0,3));
    $criteria->compare('cancel_type', $this->cancel_type, true);
    $criteria->addInCondition('cancel_type',array(0,3)); 


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'sort' => array(
            'defaultOrder' => 't.time_start DESC',
        ),
    ));
}
```

Can anyone help me out, pls?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to pass in the Hour class from the controller instead of the view and then make sure to set the attributes from the GET params that the gridview will trigger.

Maybe something like this:

```
public function actionView($id) {
    $this->layout = "//layouts/column1";

    $hour = new Hour('search');
    $hour->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if (isset($_GET['Hour'])) {
        $hour->attributes = $_GET['Hour'];
    }

    $this->render('view', array(
        'model' => $this->loadModel($id),
        'hour' => $hour,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It has not solved my problem. I think the problem is about after ajax update not reinitialize. If I use a filter (e.g. Choose an hour type, or a start date) the table refreshing but I can not use another filter. I hope I can describe somewhat clearly

Comment: I do see that you are using the bootstrap widget.

Comment: I accidentally pressed enter too soon, here is my intended comment:
I do see that you are using the 'bootstrap.widgets.BsGridView' widget. I'm sorry but I am unfamiliar with that one. I would try using the default yii CGridView widget: 'zii.widgets.grid.CGridView'. You could try generating code via the Gii tool to get filtering working by default and then modify it from there. I'm sorry if I can't be of further help.
https://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7874-tutorial-for-filtering-data-in-cgridview-widget/

Comment: Thanks! I try it as you suggested.